# Why is my setUpClass function not called when I load the test suite via defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromModule?

Tags: python

**Context**: python 2.6.5 environment

I am using `unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromModule(module)` to load tests.
However, when the following is loaded, the `setUpClass` method is not executed.

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    foo = None

    def test_choice(self):
        self.logger.info('   .. %s' % str(Full.foo))
        self.assertTrue(1 == 1)

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        logging.warn('setUpClass')
        cls.foo = settings.INITIAL
```

The returned test suites shows that it returned:

```
<unittest.TestSuite 
    tests=[<unittest.TestSuite 
         tests=[<internal.tests.master.MyTest testMethod=test_choice>]>,
```

Basically under the 'test' package, there will be many tests modules. And I want the `setUpClass` & `tearDownClass` to work for each test suites. `loadTestsFromModule` does not satisfy my requirement. Are there other ways to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works now after I upgraded to use unittest2.

Answer (score 1):

The [TestLoader.loadTestsFromModule](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.loadTestsFromModule) method is just for **loading** the test cases from your module into a test suite, you should [**run**](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite.run) your test suite if you want `setUpClass & tearDownClass` to be executed.